# Exclude torrent traffic from vpn tunnel

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have a vpn with vpn.sh (on my home network) using OpenVPN and I cant torrent over it as they dont allow it.

In order to torrent I have to turn off the vpn and then start torrenting and turn the vpn back on again.

Is there some way that I can exclude torrent traffic from going through the vpn so i dont have to keep turning it on and off?

Comment: You could use a second machine not connected to the VPN or even a Virtual machine for torrents.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem and ended up using a seperate namepace to run the torrent traffic in which was really easy to setup.
[OpenVPN for a single application on Linux](https://schnouki.net/posts/2014/12/12/openvpn-for-a-single-application-on-linux/)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. External links can break or be unavailable.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.